# how to execute multiple sql command in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have:

```
 string commandText = @"SELECT cn.companyName from Companies cn 
               INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
               WHERE uc.description like '%" + ProcessInputClause + "%';";

 string addr = @"SELECT address FROM Companies where companyName = @companyName";
```

To execute that I tried:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandText = commandText;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
   try
   {
       connection.Open();
       sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
       SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       sqlReader.Read();
       dt.Load(sqlReader);
       Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
       sqlCmd.CommandText = addr;
       SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", "namehere");
       SqlDataReader addressReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
       addressReader.Read();
       Label1.Text = Label1.Text + addressReader["address"].ToString() + addressReader.GetValue(1).ToString() + addressReader.GetString(0) + addressReader.GetString(1);
```

I can get only the first sql to execute, and get the companyName to Label1.text. But it looks like the second executeReade() gives me no result, although I tried the query alone successfully! I also tried the combine commandtext and use nextresult but no luck. Can you help me in how can I execute both command successfully ?
Ps: added calling addressReader.Read(); I forget to copy this, tried with this but no result !

Comment: let's repeat the mantra: "do not concatenate values into SQL", "do not concatenate values into SQL", "do not concatenate values into SQL"

Comment: You never call `addressReader.Read`. In any case, you really need to clean up the code, separate the two executions and and **not** try to update the UI in the same method that calls the database. **AND** don't concatenate values, pass the entire `%something%` thing as a parameter

Comment: @i_Am_Suhaim calling a stored procedure is no different than sending a raw command if the code never reads the result

Comment: @i_Am_Suhaim "use stored procedure" is not actually useful advice for most people. There was a time in the late 90s and early 00s when that was *genuinely a good idea*, but for a **long** time now, all the RDBMS have had really good cache plan re-use for parameterized SQL send as command-text. The benefits of stored procedures are pretty minimal these days, outside of a few *very* niche scenarios. Yes, it is necessary to parameterize correctly, but that is a separate concern.

Comment: Two unrelated observations: your `Read()` above `dt.Load()` is actually throwing away the top row of data; and, your second batch of code accesses 2 columns - but your query only requests 1.

Comment: The irony of finally noticing that the address comes from the same table... so: `select cn.companyName, cn.Address from ...` : *job done*

Comment: You can prepare a batch of queries and execute them all at once. This is similar to writing queries in your Query Window in Management Studio and hitting F5. But I'd prefer using a stored proc to this. Keeps code clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to do is to parameterize that first query ;p

After that, all you *need* to change here is to actually consume the second reader:

```
using(var addressReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    if(addressReader.Read()) {
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + addressReader["address"].ToString()
         + addressReader.GetValue(1).ToString() + addressReader.GetString(0)
         + addressReader.GetString(1);
    }
}
```

EDIT: removing this, as it doesn't apply since the two queries are hierarchical

<strike>You *could* perform both selects in a single sql operation (`NextResult()`, etc), but I'm not sure that `dt.Load` will work well with that; worth a try, though:</strike>

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"
    SELECT cn.companyName from Companies cn 
    INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
    WHERE uc.description like '%' + @description+ '%';

    SELECT address FROM Companies where companyName = @companyName;";

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", ProcessInputClause);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", "namehere");
using(var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    dt.Load(reader);
    if(reader.NextResult() && reader.Read()) {
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + reader["address"].ToString()
         + reader.GetValue(1).ToString() + reader.GetString(0)
         + reader.GetString(1);
    }
}
```

With a dependency between the queries, and the fact that the address is part of the company record, I would just do this:

```
@"SELECT cn.companyName, cn.Address from Companies cn 
           INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
           WHERE uc.description like '%" + @description + "%';";
```

a single query that fetches both values. You could use your existing `dt.Load` to access that, getting the name from the first column and the address from the second - but frankly I'm a huge fan of "dapper", so I'd do it this way:

```
class Company {
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
...
var rows = conn.Query<Company>(
    @"SELECT cn.companyName, cn.Address from Companies cn 
      INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
      WHERE uc.description like '%" + @description + "%';",
    new { description = ProcessInputClause }).ToList();
```

then just iterate over `rows`:

```
foreach(var row in rows) {
    string name = row.CompanyName;
    string address = row.Address;
    // ...
}
```

Or if you don't want to declare the type:

```
var rows = conn.Query(
    @"SELECT cn.companyName, cn.Address from Companies cn 
      INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
      WHERE uc.description like '%" + @description + "%';",
    new { description = ProcessInputClause }).ToList();
foreach(var row in rows) {
    string name = row.companyName; // yes, this works
    string address = row.Address;
    // ...
}
```

---

In the scenario where multiple tables are involved, you can use a table-variable as the base for joins:

```
declare @ids table (CompanyId int not null)
insert @ids (CompanyId)
select companyId from Companies cn
INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
WHERE uc.description like '%" + @description + "%';

select cn.CompanyName, cn.Address
from @ids #i
inner join Companies cn on cn.CompanyId = #i.CompanyId

select /* other stuff */
from @ids #i
inner join /* other tables */

select /* yet more other stuff */
from @ids #i
inner join /* yet more other tables */
```

Comment: can I use sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", "namehere"); inside the using(var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())? because I need to add like this: sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());

Comment: @user1314404 ah, right - then you need either two separate queries or a much more complicated single query - two separate queries is probably simpler. Let me rewrite a different way a moment...

Comment: @user1314404 question: how many companies, and how many addresses, are you expecting?

Comment: The query for CompanyName will return many names. So for each name I need to query different address. One company name will have only one address.

Comment: @user1314404 see the edit; if `Address` is a column on `cn`, this is actually really really simple; no need for two queries *at all*

Comment: Dear Marc, I know since address and company name in the same table it will be simple. But I just make my question simpler, actually I need to execute 4 queries beside companyName, and the fields are from different tables! You can refer to my question here for detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909033/how-to-avoid-duplication-in-sql-connection-and-execute-command/23909671#23909671.

Comment: Your first suggestion working well! I would love to see if the second method of combining query can work also.

Comment: @user if the queries are separate, then *either* you need to simply loop and query per-company-name, or you need to write a complicated single query; I'll add an example of that - final edit!

Comment: Do you see any error with this statement: sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", "namehere"); Just now I success when I used the query with no @companyName, but I put the real name string inside, then comment out the addwithvalue later. But now I use variable in the sql and transfer value it doesn't work!

Comment: @user1314404 "it doesn't work" is not sufficient. What happens?

Comment: I shouldn't put @ at Addwithvalue, it stated correctly in your answer! Amazing, speed, precise and complete solution! Thank you !

Comment: Can I ask, why I repeat the step and the if condition never satisfy? sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            sqlCmd.CommandText = standards;
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                            using (var standardsReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (standardsReader.Read()) {
                                    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + standardsReader["name"].ToString(); } }

Comment: @user1314404 I cannot debug you application from here; you are going to have to try running the sql with the value to figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can put both commands on an string array and do foreach statement command in commands.

Like this:

```
string command1 = @"SELECT cn.companyName from Companies cn 
               INNER JOIN KeyProcesses uc ON uc.companyId = cn.companyId  
               WHERE uc.description like '%" + ProcessInputClause + "%';";
string command2 = @"SELECT address FROM Companies where companyName = @companyName";

string[] commands  = new string[2];
        commands.SetValue(command1 , 0);
        commands.SetValue(command2 , 1);
```

Then:

```
Foreach(string command in commands)
{
    SqlCommand c= new SqlCommand(command , connection);
    //do the rest
}
```

Comment: @chridam everyone seems to be getting one; sometimes, people are just grumpy

Comment: SetValue is to transfer value "0" and "1" to variable @companyName isn't it ?

Comment: @user1314404 Nope, commands.SetValue(command1 , 0); transfers the first string command to the first index of the string array! Applies to the second SetValue too.

Comment: @MarcGravell And quick to pull the trigger at times :-)

Comment: It is unclear to me *why* you would initialize the arrays that way (or indeed why you would use arrays at all here), but a simpler way would be : `var commands = new[] {command1, command2};`, which has the same result

Comment: @MarcGravell Correct but as you now better than me there are many ways to achieve a goal in coding, as long as they yield the same result. Indeed your way is simpler though. :)

Comment: Even if the loop guarantees `ExecuteReader` gets called, the two commands require a different way to pass parameters and extract the results (DataTable vs single row). Even if you convert it to a `for` loop, you'd still end up with needless conditional logic. I don't see how this can improve the situation, much less solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

Use DataSet instead of Datatable

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);


SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, connection);

da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: `DataTable` by itself is bad enough; what has the OP done to you to annoy you so much that you would wish `DataSet` upon them?