# How to pass value to sql command in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL command:

```
string keyProcesses = "SELECT distinct STUFF((SELECT ', '+ cn.name  from WMCCMCategories cn  INNER JOIN CategorySets uc ON uc.categoryId = cn.categoryID INNER JOIN KeyProcesses u ON u.categorySetId = uc.setId  INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.companyId = u.companyId  WHERE c.companyName = @companyName  ORDER BY cn.name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr FROM WMCCMCategories cnn Group by cnn.name";
```

And I have:

```
public SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandText = commandText; //where commandText is another SQL statement
sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

Then I execute connection:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        sdr.Fill(dt)
```

After that I want to move to the next SQL command and add parameter to that command:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = keyProcesses;
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", compnyName);
SqlDataAdapter sdr1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
DataTable dtb1 = new DataTable();
sdr1.Fill(dtb1);
```

But it fail to execute this `SqlCommand`. I already make sure that the SQL key process can run properly with a fix parameter pre-added in. The `compnName` is not empty. The only suspect here is how to add value to sql parameter. I don't know what is wrong in my way of using it ?

Edit: I update the whole part of code for the easy of investigating the issue:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
                    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
                    sdr.Fill(dt);
                        //To store the values of company names:
                    List<CompanyModel> companies = new List<CompanyModel>();


                        for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            companies.Add(new CompanyModel 
                            { 
                                compnSN = i + 1,
                                compnName =  dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString(),
                                compnAddress =  dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString()
                            });
                        }

                        companyRepeater.DataSource = companies;
                        companyRepeater.DataBind();

                        string comName = dt.Rows[0]["companyName"].ToString();
                        var names = companies.Select(c => c.compnName);

                        string[] arr = names.ToArray();
                        foreach (string compnyName in arr)
                        {
                            //To write names to file for debugging purpose
                            using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"), true))
                            {

                                _testData.WriteLine(compnyName); // Write the file.
                            }


                              //Get KeyProcesses
                              sqlCmd.CommandText = keyProcesses;
                              //sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", compnyName);
                              sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                              sqlCmd.Parameters["@companyName"].Value = compnyName;
                             // SqlDataAdapter sdr1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
                              DataTable dtb1 = new DataTable();
                              //sdr1.Fill(dtb1);
                              using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                              {
                                  dtb1.Load(reader);
                              }

                              companies.Add(new CompanyModel
                              {
                                  compnKeyProcesses = dtb1.Rows[0][0].ToString()

                              });
```

Comment: Isn't there a typo ? cfr "compnyName" in `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", compnyName);`

Comment: What is the error? Why don't you just use a new object?

Comment: Personally, I would strongly suggest that `DataTable` is of little benefit here. `DataTable` was useful for migrating from ADO.NET record sets; however, that was 10 years ago. It should *not* be your default data tool (except for a few scenarios involving unknown schemas). I would strongly suggest moving to a more object-based approach for data.

Comment: I suppose that `SqlCommand command` is just a typo? It should be `SqlCommand sqlCmd`

Comment: Looks like you pointed out my problem !

Comment: With this modification, I can run through the first foreach loop, but do you know why at the second loop, I can only run to the using (var reader = ...? then it go to the catch exception with the same error? I am sure that the compnyName is different string now and sql query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you don't need the adapter here at all. It adds only confusion. Remove it:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = keyProcesses;
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", compnyName);
using(var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    dtb1.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: I already try without adapter, Use, using as you said, what is the difference to that ?

Comment: @user1314404 and what happened when you did that? it should work fine. If you are asking "what does the `using` do?" - it ensures that the reader is disposed after use. (almost) all use of `IDisposable` objects should make use of `using` - that includes connections and commands too. And lots of other things.

Comment: Oh, I mean will this help to make sure the value will be added to the sql ? I want to use adapter because I can use sdr1.Fill)dtb1), that command make sure that I have the first record. If I use dtb1.Load(reader) I think I miss the first record.

Comment: @user1314404 the `.Parameters.AddWithValue` is what adds the parameter value (assuming that `compnyName` is not `null` - if it is, you need to do something a bit different). No, `dtb1.Load(reader)` does not miss the first record. It would only do that if you called `reader.Read();` before the `.Load(reader);`

Comment: @user1314404 and I look at your question May 29th, and you are, sure enough, doing `sqlReader.Read(); dt.Load(sqlReader);`. And guess what: I told you about it then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929374/how-to-execute-multiple-sql-command-in-asp-net#comment36854948_23929374

Comment: I used your code above, and debug, I can see that It only run to the line, using (var reader = ...) but it not run inside: dtb1.Load(reader), it run to catch(exception ex). And yes, compnyName is not Null. It is a string name.

Comment: It is the same thing happen with my code above with adapter. I use debug and I see the sql is still with @companyName; meaning that the value is not transfer into the parameter. I really don't know why is that.

Comment: @user1314404 sql parameterization is **not** based on string-replace. It is **expected** that the final SQL includes `@companyName`. The database server knows how to handle parameters, and is given the command and parameter values **separately**.

Comment: @user1314404 if it throws an exception, please indicate exactly what the exception says.

Comment: I get this: {"Invalid attempt to call Depth when reader is closed."} System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: @user1314404 that suggests that you got your `using` and `Load` in the wrong places

Comment: what you mean by "wrong places" ? when I have sql right, parameter is not null, so I can just call it anywhere isn't it ?

Comment: @user1314404 I mean: your reader seems to be closed before you call `.Load`. That suggests you have copied some code incorrectly. Without the current code, I can't say "where"

Comment: It run smoothly until it reach using (var reader = .... So I guess that is the place having problem. Ok, let me update my question by the whole code then!

Comment: Can I load(reader) again in my above foreach loop? Because at the second loop round, I got the catch exception

Comment: It turn out that I need to reset the new command and connection everytime I loop again and use using( var reader ... again. Something like this: sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();sqlCmd.Connection = connection; I will accept your answer as my solution. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName", SqlDbType.NVarchar(1000));  // or whatever type your
                                                                     database column has

sqlCmd.Parameters["@companyName"].Value = compnyName;

this is a more secure way and might help

Comment: It doesn't help, sorry! I got the same problem, it will not run inside the loading result to datatable, but it run to the catch exception, as I mention in my comment on Marc's answer.